# JQuery Slideing effect not working?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, javascript, client-side-scripting

for me JQuery Slideing effect not working? I trid many times but nothing happens.

I used the latest version of browsers and tested in all leading browsers but no response.

the html code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript" >

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$(function () {
    $("#slide_up_link").click(function () {
        $("#mydiv").slideUp("slow");
    });

    $("#slide_down_link").click(function () {
        $("#mydiv").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("#toggle23").click(function () {
        $("#mydiv").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});


</script>
<style>
div#mydiv
 {
 border:  1px solid white;
  }


</style>

</head>

 <body>
 <button id="#slide_up_link">UP</ button>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;<buttonid="#slide_down_link">down</ button>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<button id="#toggle23">toggle</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <div id="#mydiv" >
 <p>hai how are you </p><br>
  <p>i am fine </p><br>
 <p> bye</p><br>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But when i click the buttons nothing happens. WHY? Please explain breifly because i am new to JQuery and javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery selector does not match because of the HTML attribute `id="#id"`, it should be `id="id"`.  The `#` is a reserved character in CSS selectors like `.`.
Here's a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v375N/2/

Comment: "You should try to learn HTML first" - There is no need to answer the @Ragesh Antony like that,you too was a student at some point.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is -> http://jsfiddle.net/2aLv4/

Just need to fix your HTML, the JS is fine.

You should not use # in your HTML ids and also there is a line that is like this

```
buttonid=
```

That should be fixed too.